# using hook_node_submit to create an alternate upload method

Tags: hooks, files

We have a problem where we are uploading a number of files on a regular basis, the files need to be kept outside of the document root.

Each file is attached to a node.

I created a folder `/documentstore` and all the files are uploaded to there.

To enable submission of documents I added a symlink `sites/default/files/documentstore -> /documentstore`

Unfortunately drupal does not allow files uploads to a symlinked folder :( I have modified core to solve the issue as a temporary fix.

For a more permanent fix I'd like to add a module hook node submission and then copy the file to the symlinked folder avoiding drupals core upload function. I am trying to use `hook_node_submit()`.

I would like some hints as to how I can go about this or whether there is a better way to store files outside of the docroot (yes it must be done that way)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the copy function to store the files to different location other than drupal root or files folder.

Alter `hook_node_submit` function using copy instead of `file_save_upload`.

Try referring Drupal S3 module code, which copies the files to AWS S3 storage.

Comment: Thanks Kalpan. I have created a solution. Nothing like posting on stackexchange to get your mind to go down different paths.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my dilemma was simpler than I had imagined.

The problem of saving into symlinked folders is discussed here.. https://www.drupal.org/node/1008402 with a few patches to fix `getlocalpath()`. This was the basis for my temporary fix.

5 years and no patch has made it to production!

After posting here and struggling to get the solution working, which was being complicated by the module `filefield_paths` altering the workflow somewhat (files aren't save to the final location till later). I realised if I can create my own streamwrapper I can save the files where I like.

This turned out to be very easy and worked a treat.

I will post a link to the streamwrapper module when I have cleaned it up and submitted it to drupal.

I have created a sandbox project for this module here https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/developerchris/2644230